# How to check if element is not visible due to parent is hidden thanks its class

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance, element, visibility

I have an array of checkboxes and want to switch them (check/uncheck) as a group, but only these which are really visible.

```
<style id=dynamicStyle>DIV.filterLevel3{display:none;}</style>
<div class="filterLevel3">
    <input type=checkbox id=cbx_123456 name=cbx_123456 class=cbxForSwitch>
    ... more elements belonging to the checkbox, 
    ... always hidden on shown together
</div>
```

The dynamicStyle.innerHTML may be changed by another javascript. Changing the visibility works fine, but I need to select all checkboxes of class "cbxForSwitch" that are currently visible.

I have seen many examples using jQuery, but all of them were inspecting css attributes of said element or his style etc. I need to get actual visibility after the explorer have implemented all rules of style including inheritance.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking - but have you looked into https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: Yes, it works. $(...).filter(":visible") returns only really visible elements. Thank you. Set it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can get the parent element's css attributes by using the parent() function. If the parent's 'display' css property is set to none, you can then check the box by using the jquery function prop().

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().css('display') !== 'none') {
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martiensk/eq0qabxm/)

Comment: It doesn't work. Visibility can be affected not only by immediate parent or his css. Some distant parent can have a class or more classes which can have display:none and the priority is known only to explorer.